# p:ajax rowSelect event activates on p:commandButton click

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I have my datatable with selections and ajax event:

```
     <p:dataTable id="targetTable" value="#{targetController.targetList}" var="target emptyMessage="No result found with given criteria"
            widgetVar="targetTable" paginator="true" rows="20" selection="#{targetController.editTarget}" selectionMode="single" paginatorPosition="top"
           rowsPerPageTemplate="5,20,50" lazy="true"
            >
            <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{targetController.editTarget}" />

            ... columns ..
      </p:dataTable>
```

And I added column with button like this:

```
      <p:column width="100"><f:facet name="header">#{i.m['Changes history']}</f:facet>
                <p:commandButton id="showChangesHistory" value="#{i.m['Show Changes']}"  onclick="return false;" type="button" />
      </p:column>
```

My problem is that `targetController.editTarget` activates on button click.

Primefaces version: 3.3.1

Comment: would you consider using the `selectionMode` attribute on a column, instead of the whole table? like this:

`<p:column selectionMode="single"/>`

Comment: specifing `selectionMode` on a column would be enough or I need to specify `selection` also ?

Comment: `selection` can remain on the table, as it is done in this tutorial: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/selection.xhtml

Comment: unfortunately, current behavior is that edit page launches on click on a row. Adding selectionMode=single on column transforms it to column of radiobuttons and remove current on click event, so it is not an acceptable solution.

Comment: Could you try process="@this" on the button

Comment: It doesn't work. I added info about my primefaces version.

Comment: please take a look at here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14879193/primefaces-exclude-column-from-row-selection-in-pdatatable